# How to make Vim display colors as indicated by color codes?

Tags: vim, colors, pager

In short, I'm in an effort to replace `less` with `vim` (`vimpager`). I have settings for scripts to spit out colors (and bold and everything nice) whenever they can. `less` understands the color codes and displays them nicely. How can I make `vim` parse the codes and display colors/boldness the way `less` does?

Comment: If you want a full blown pager based on vim try [vimpager](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager) or my rewrite for neovim: [nvimpager](https://github.com/lucc/nvimpager). They use AnsiEsc and a rewrite in lua respectively, and wrap it all up into a script that can be used as a pager without further hacking on your part.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Two answers:

A short one:  you want to use the vim script [AnsiEsc.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302).  It will conceal the actual ANSI escape sequences in your file, and use syntax highlighting to color the text appropriately.  The problem with using this in a pager is that you will have to make vim recognize when to use this.  I am not sure if you can simply always load it, or if it will conflict with other syntax files.  You will have to experiment with it.

A long answer: The best you can hope for is a partial non-portable solution.   Less does not actually understand the terminal escape sequences, since these are largely terminal dependent, but less can recognize (a subset of) these, and will know to pass them through to the terminal, if you use the `-r` (or `-R`) option. The terminal will interprets the escape sequences and changes the attributes of the text (color, bold, underline ...). Vim, being an editor rather than a pager, does not simply pass raw control characters to the terminal.  It needs to display them in some way, so you can actually edit them.  You can use other features of vim, such as concealment and syntax highlighting to hide the sequences and use them for setting colors of the text, however, it will always handle only a subset of the terminal sequences, and will probably not work on some terminals.

This is really just one of many issues you will run into when you try to use a text editor as a pager.

Comment: To put it in a nutshell, you have to write part of a terminal emulator in Vim, the part that handles the terminal escape sequences that are present in your input.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm giving up. If it's not easy it doesn't make much sense anymore.

Comment: By the way, if all you are trying to do is have a pager with syntax highlighting, look at this link: http://linux-tips.org/article/78/syntax-highlighting-in-less

Comment: @JanHlavacek link is broken :(

Comment: @Nitrodist, Looks fixed now if you still need it.

Comment: @Nitrodist: `less -r FILE` ([source](http://superuser.com/a/218823/84963))

Comment: It seems Jan's link has moved to https://linux-tips.com/t/how-to-enable-syntax-highlighting-in-less/208

Comment: To install the script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033078/how-to-install-a-vimball-plugin-with-vba-extension

Answer (score 34):

Now with vim 8 you can use terminal mode `:terminal` and then in that terminal do `cat myfile` and go back to normal mode with Ctrl-w N. This will display ANSI color codes correctly. By automating these steps and reading from standard input instead of a file, it should be possible to use vim to replace less.

For example, you can run `ls --color=always >/tmp/colored.txt`

or `unbuffer ls >/tmp/colored.txt`

and then in vim `:terminal cat /tmp/colored.txt` followed by `:only`

Then you will have the ls output nicely colored in vim like `less` would do. As vim supports passing commands as command-line arguments on startup, it is clearly possible to fiddle around to make that solution work for replacing less :)

Comment: I took your idea and ran with it! https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/94024fac52780e03c936589f4c9ab914

Comment: Neovim can do the same, but use `<c-\><c-n>` to go back to normal mode.

Comment: Just Wow! This should be the accepted answer!...Except that if a file is too long (11M in my case), :terminal cat will truncate and loose the head :S

Comment: "The commands that would start insert mode, such as 'i' and 'a', return to **Terminal-Job** mode." Then the terminal can be exited. P.S. I am on Vim 8.2, and it has both `<C-w>N` and `<C-\><C-n>` listed for entering **Terminal-Normal** mode.

Comment: Meh. You can look, but not touch.

Comment: `:terminal cat` performance not good for large files, but `:AnsiEsc` fine

Answer (score 16):

Install the vim plugin [Improved AnsiEsc](https://github.com/powerman/vim-plugin-AnsiEsc)
and put the below on your .profile/bash_profile/zprofile and you are good to go.

```bsh
export PAGER="vim -R +AnsiEsc"
```

Comment: This is a great answer, +1 for export command.

Comment: Does this works on vim 7.x or its vim 8.x solution?

Answer (score 2):

I installed [AnsiEsc](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) like the others and then added the following to my _vimrc:

```
command Log colorscheme elflord | %s/\[39m//g | AnsiEsc
```

Now, when I load a file that contains a bunch of color control characters, I type:

```
:Log
```

And it looks like the command line, but I'm editing!

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You can use vim's json syntax highlighting.  Normally comes in most default vim installs.  May not be all as pretty as the `less -R` BUT..

- If you have python, this makes is human readable with the `-mjson.tool`

```
cat filename | python -mjson.tool | vim -c 'set syntax=json' -
```

- If you don't have python but your json is pretty printed

```
cat filename | vim -c 'set syntax=json' -
```

Also some browsers have json extensions, and you could pipe it into the browser.  Hmmm I wonder if `w3m` might suffice for a pure cli effort.

Hope that helps.